# Check whether the line starts with point and then delete it

Tags: java, string

I am trying to delete lines start with `.` in my parsed text document. With the current code no line starts with point is being deleted. How can I fix that? I have tried it without `\\` but the result is the same.

**Simple:**

```
... ...
```

**Code:**

```
if (line.startsWith("\\.")) {                   
    outputLine = line.replace(".", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) doesn't evaluate a regex, it just takes the string as is. As such, there's no need to escape the `.`:

```
if(line.startsWith(".")){
    outputLine = line.replace(".", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with `indexOf` function, like this:

```
if(line.indexOf(".") == 0)
{
   outputLine = line.replace("."," ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.charAt(0)` to get the first character, and you could use `String.substring(1)` to get the `String` minus its' first character. Something like

```
String line = ".Hello";
if (line.charAt(0) == '.') {
    line = line.substring(1);
}
System.out.println(line);
```

Output is

```
Hello
```

You might also omit the test and use a regular expression with `String.replaceAll(String, String)` like

```
String line = ".Hello";
line = line.replaceAll("^\\.", ""); // <-- starts with .
System.out.println(line);
```

for the sample output.